# While Running Java program getting error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am a little bit confused about Array.

While I Run this program I got an error.

```
class Insurance {
public static void main(String args []) {
    int age;
    String gen;
    String status;
    age = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    gen = args[1];
    status = args[2];
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Married"))
     System.out.println("Insurance Given!");
    else if(gen.equalsIgnoreCase("Male") && age>30)
     System.out.println("Insurance Given");
    else if(gen.equalsIgnoreCase("Female") && age>25)
     System.out.println("Insurance Given");
    else 
     System.out.println("Insurance Denied");
     
}
```

}

**Output**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0at Insurance.main(Insurance.java:9)

Comment: You need to add details about how you run the code and why you expect the args array to have any data in it, as you've written in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass arguments to a main()

```
compile by > javac Insurance.java  
run by > java Insurance 50 Male Married
```

In above case:

```
args[0] = 50
args[1] = Male
args[2] = Married
```

If any argument is missing it will throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can check number  of arguments like this:

```
if(args.length == 3) {     
    //the last argument is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run this code using the command line.
Go to the file location.

Open command line and Compile your class

**javac Insurance.java**

then run your class and use this command like this example.

**java Insurance.java 12 Male Married**

Thanks